# use of extensions in Swift

Tags: swift

I am looking at some sample code from some Apple Developer sample projects and I see this pattern repeating quite a few times.

So there is a view controller...

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
}
```

and then there is always some extension to that as something like:

```
extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
   ...
}
```

I am wondering why it is done like this? Is this to allow reusability of the initial defined classes or is there some other reason?

Comment: You can choose to use this pattern or you can choose to not use it, in other words it doesn't affect the functionality of the class and it's mostly a matter of opinion.

Comment: Above and beyond basic code organization (to clearly demarcate which methods are for which protocol, to group all of these related functions together), it also enables better code navigation. Xcode allows you to “collapse” and “expand” blocks of code. E.g., when working on your `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` conformance, expand that section and collapse others. When you’re done with it, collapse that extension and get it out of the way as you focus on other areas of your code,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's in the same file, it's just for code organization purposes. It's convenient to keep methods together that relate to a specific protocol. It's a good reminder not to change the names of those methods, and it makes clear why a method might seem never to be called (since it's called from Apple code, for example).

If it's in another file, it's sometimes to simplify code-reuse, particularly if a very general-purpose type is conformed to a very app-specific protocol. But even in that case, it may just be for organizational purposes, to make files smaller, or just to express that you consider this to be non-core functionality.

But broadly, extensions are a very common and general-purpose tool that you can use whenever you find them convenient and meaningful.

Comment: People were already trying to approximate this in Objective C using `#pragma MARK`. Now we've lifted the concept and made it first class. I love it.

Comment: @Alexander Unfortunately, the way that Xcode lists these in the drop-down isn't really that great (especially if you're using this to separate private methods), so I wind up adding `// MARK - ...` anyway :D

Comment: In addition to the points you make, it's also possible to add extensions to classes that don't belong to you. That can be useful to add functions/computed properties to system classes or third party libraries, even if you don't have access to their source code.

Answer (score 1):

Contributing to the answer, this is to better organize your projects, and not having such a ViewController:

```swift
extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ... {
    ...
}
```

Not only making use of Apple protocols but also organizing your methods into extensions.

For example, I organized my main ViewController with view creation methods to code, something like this:

```swift
extension MainViewController {
    private func createView() {
    ...
    }

   private func configureConstraints() {
    ...
    }
}
```